# Updating values in MySQL view

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose we have these tables:

***events***

```
id | name  | time      | action | entered
---+-------+-----------+--------+--------
 1 | james | today     | x      |
 1 | james | today     | x      | yes
 1 | james | today     | y      |
 1 | james | today     | y      | yes
 2 | carl  | today     | x      | 
 2 | carl  | today     | y      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | x      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | x      | yes
 3 | casey | yesterday | y      |
 3 | casey | yesterday | y      | yes
 4 | john  | today     | x      | yes
```

***users***

```
name  | email        |   
------+--------------+
james | james@email  |   
casey | casey@email  |
```

Can I create a ***view*** which yields the following?:

**EventsView**

```
id | name        | time      | action | entered
---+-------------+-----------+--------+--------
 1 | james@email | today     | x      |
 1 | james@email | today     | x      | yes
 1 | james@email | today     | y      |
 1 | james@email | today     | y      | yes
 2 | carl        | today     | x      | 
 2 | carl        | today     | y      |
 3 | casey@email | yesterday | x      |
 3 | casey@email | yesterday | x      | yes
 3 | casey@email | yesterday | y      |
 3 | casey@email | yesterday | y      | yes
 4 | john        | today     | x      | yes
```

That is, I want to see the user names, for which I have an email for, as the email, not the name itself. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use a `left join` along with the `coalesce` function that will return the first non null value of its arguments. Like this:

```
select 
  e.id, coalesce(u.email, e.name) name, e.time, e.action, e.entered
from events e 
left join users u on e.name = u.name
```

[Live example with a view.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/631022/1)

Comment: this seems to work! I'm going to test my data set with this. However I do notice that this very efficient, for a large data set, correct? Thanks so much!